# java script Mobile keydown

Tags: javascript, input, keydown

Hi im new with js an i have a problem with keydown:
i can´t get a response from my code on mobile chrome.

```
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const inputField = document.getElementById("input");
  inputField.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.code === "Enter") {
      let input = inputField.value;
      inputField.value = "";
      output(input);
     }
    });
   });
```

Comment: which browser/platform?

Comment: Did you see what the value of `e.code` looks like on mobile?

Comment: Could it be that the mobile platform/browser doesn't fire the `keydown` event? Maybe it only fires on change/blur?

Comment: I think you need `e.key` instead of `e.code` when trying to match `”Enter”`